# Website looks fine in PC at different widths but breaks in mobile phone

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I was practicing taking a website from the web and copy it with Photoshop then coding it up.  I noticed though that I can view the page in different width of my browser and although it isn't responsive, none of the divs overlap or break the basic design.  But when I view it in my mobile phone the search bar overlaps and gets moved away from its container.  I included a pic of this view in my browser. **Why is it breaking on mobile-phone?** Here's the heroku link to it too: 
https://still-beach-27404.herokuapp.com/

**Broken website on mobile phone**
[image: Website on Mobile Phone]

**Looks fine on PC at shrunken width**
[image: Website on PC with smaller width]

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: why is it breaking...sorry was implied.

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear on what you want from reading your question. But maybe try adding this to your head tag if it isnt there already?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This usually fix my problems with different devices.

Comment: I think what's actually required is to remove the viewport tag, as the site is not responsive.

Comment: I added this already thinking that was the issue.  But it still looks like the search bar isn't in its parent container and is removed onto another block.  I'll try to float the search left see if that works.

Comment: I removed the <meta> element from my <head> but that didn't work as well @DanDevine